# Which npm version is correct?

Tags: npm

I just install npm 2.11.1,but when I use `npm -v` command it tells me the version is 2.10.1.

I want to know what's wrong and how can I handle it?

My computer is Windows operating system

Comment: Are you sure you installed version 2.11.1? How did you install it?

Comment: I used the command `npm install npm` in windows and it shows me npm @2.11.1 node_modules\npm.Isn't main that the version is 2.11.1?

Comment: you can update your npm by using `npm install -g npm` command

Comment: I had tried,but it's still 2.10.1

Answer (score 0):

If you install [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) you can update your npm to the latest stable version by this command

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

**UPDATE :**
for windows you can [download](http://nodejs.org/download/) and run the latest MSI. The MSI will update your installed node and npm.

Comment: I had tried,but it's not work,it seems work on Linux but my operating system is windows....